# I think boost-jam, bjam and boost-bjam should be the same tag

Tags: discussion

I think boost-jam, bjam and boost-bjam should be the same tag, but I'm not entirely sure since I haven't actually used this build system.

- [bjam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bjam): 187
- [boost-jam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost-jam): 73
- [boost-bjam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost-bjam): 6

Only the first tag has a description. I think it would best phrasing-wise if the first and the third were aliases of the second.

What say you?

Comment: See also: [b2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/b2)

Comment: I say: merge merge merge